# Angular routing with nested modules and nested redirectTo

Tags: angular, module, routes, children

I have 3 modules, one nested inside the other (with lazyloading).

The site initially loads at `http://localhost:4200/` and Module A displays, there is an option in Module A for the user to go to `http://localhost:4200/moduleB`,

The intended affect is that `http://localhost:4200/moduleB` will redirect to `http://localhost:4200/moduleB/moduleC` automatically (moduleB will be a thing in the future, just not currently ready)

What do I need to fix to ensure intended behavior, because this is not working.

ModuleA

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ModuleAComponent},
  { path: 'moduleB', loadChildren: './modules/moduleB/moduleB.module#ModuleBModule'},
];

@NgModule({imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]})
export class ModuleARouting { }
```

ModuleB

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: "/moduleB/moduleC" },
  { path: 'moduleC', loadChildren: './moduleC/moduleC.module#moduleCModule'},
];

@NgModule({imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]})
export class ModuleBRouting { }
```

ModuleC

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: "/moduleB/moduleC/ModuleCComponent"},
  { path: "ModuleCComponent", component: ModuleCComponent},   
];

@NgModule({imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]})
export class ApplicationRouting { }
```

Comment: The first question would be: why are you trying to load a module that doesn’t do anything.. ? Also, what Angular version are you on because that is the old way of lazy loading..

Comment: @MikeOne moduleB will eventually have it's own components. At the moment it does not, but structure needs to be in place for future. I am using Angular 9. I should also add that I was not aware of a newer way to lazy load.

Comment: Does it help if you use the new import way of lazy loading? I would expect your setup to work really..?